# Balance dataset using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, machine-learning

This is for a machine learning program.

I am working with a [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/histopathologic-cancer-detection/data) that has a csv which contains an id, for a `.tif` image in another directory, and a label, 1 or 0. There are 220,025 rows in the csv. I have loaded this csv as a pandas dataframe. Currently in the dataframe, there are 220,025 rows, with 130,908 rows with label 0 and 89,117 rows with label 1.

There are 41,791 more rows with label 0 than label 1. I want to randomly drop the extra rows with label 1. After that, I want to decrease the sample size from 178,234 to just 50,000, with 25,000 ids for each label.

Another approach might be to randomly drop 105,908 rows with label 1 and 64,117 with label 0.

How can I do this using pandas?

I have already looked at using `.groupby` and then using `.sample`, but that drops an equal amount of rows in both labels, while I only want to drop rows in one label.

Sample of the csv:

```
id,label
f38a6374c348f90b587e046aac6079959adf3835,0
c18f2d887b7ae4f6742ee445113fa1aef383ed77,1
755db6279dae599ebb4d39a9123cce439965282d,0
bc3f0c64fb968ff4a8bd33af6971ecae77c75e08,0
068aba587a4950175d04c680d38943fd488d6a9d,0
acfe80838488fae3c89bd21ade75be5c34e66be7,0
a24ce148f6ffa7ef8eefb4efb12ebffe8dd700da,1
7f6ccae485af121e0b6ee733022e226ee6b0c65f,1
559e55a64c9ba828f700e948f6886f4cea919261,0
8eaaa7a400aa79d36c2440a4aa101cc14256cda4,0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would break it up into the following steps:

Since you have more 0s than 1s, we're first going to ensure that we even out the number of each. Here, I'm using the sample data you pasted in as `df`

- Count the number of 1s (since this is our smaller value)

```
ones_subset = df.loc[df["label"] == 1, :]
number_of_1s = len(ones_subset)

print(number_of_1s)
3
```

- Sample only the zeros to match the number of `number_of_1s`

```
zeros_subset = df.loc[df["label"] == 0, :]
sampled_zeros = zeros_subset.sample(number_of_1s)

print(sampled_zeros)
```

- Stick these 2 chunks (all of the 1s from our `ones_subset` and our matched `sampled_zeros` together to make one clean dataframe that has an equal number of 1 and 0 labels

```
clean_df = pd.concat([ones_subset, sampled_zeros], ignore_index=True)

print(clean_df)
                                         id  label
0  c18f2d887b7ae4f6742ee445113fa1aef383ed77      1
1  a24ce148f6ffa7ef8eefb4efb12ebffe8dd700da      1
2  7f6ccae485af121e0b6ee733022e226ee6b0c65f      1
3  559e55a64c9ba828f700e948f6886f4cea919261      0
4  f38a6374c348f90b587e046aac6079959adf3835      0
5  068aba587a4950175d04c680d38943fd488d6a9d      0
```

Now that we have a cleaned up dataset, we can proceed with the last step:

- Use the `groupby(...).sample(...)` approach you mentioned to further downsample this dataset. Taking this from a dataset that has 3 of each label (three 1s and three 0s) to a smaller matched size- (two 1s and two 0s)

```
downsampled_df = clean_df.groupby("label").sample(2)

print(downsampled_df)
                                         id  label
4  f38a6374c348f90b587e046aac6079959adf3835      0
5  068aba587a4950175d04c680d38943fd488d6a9d      0
1  a24ce148f6ffa7ef8eefb4efb12ebffe8dd700da      1
0  c18f2d887b7ae4f6742ee445113fa1aef383ed77      1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I implemented it and it worked. I also shuffled the dataframe and reset the index afterwards. Thanks for the help!